# How to download package "markovchain" for R version less than 3.6

Tags: r, markov

I have R version of 3.4.4 loaded on my laptop but I want to download package "markovchain" in my R.
THE CODE I USED WAS

```
install.packages("markovchain", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

BUT I RECEIVED THE FOLLOWING ERROR

```
 Warning in install.packages :
      package ‘markovchain’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

IS THERE A WAY TO SPECIFY WHICH VERSION OF R I WANT TO DOWNLOAD THE PACKAGE FOR ??

Comment: [The current version requires R (>= 3.6.0).](https://cran.r-project.org/package=markovchain) In order to use this package with older R versions, you need to download an older package version from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/markovchain/) and build it from source. Of course, you might need to do the same for packages in the dependency tree. That could potentially be a non-trivial amount of work. Personally, I'd rather update R (3.4.4 is truly ancient).

Comment: Thanks @Roland but the thing is that my laptops specifications only allow R with such lower versions to run. So according to your advice i will archive an old package

Comment: I'm not aware of a change in system requirements between 3.4.4 and 4.0.2.